# Difference between Tafel and Whiteboard

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was trying to understand the difference between Tafel and Whiteboard, do they have a different meaning?

Having some examples:

> Konrad, schreib deine Ergebnisse an die **Tafel**.
>
> Konrad, write your results on the board.

And

> Fragen Sie den potenziellen Kunden, ob Sie das **Whiteboard** statt einer
>   PowerPoint-Präsentation verwenden können.
>
> Ask the prospect if you can use the whiteboard instead of a PowerPoint
>   presentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I grew up in a time when no whiteboards existed. Therefore, for me a *Tafel* was always a blackboard, since otherwise you wouldn't be able to see the white chalk on it.

Now that I'm adult and whiteboards are common in business use, the word *Tafel* still means a blackboard (irrelevant in my daily life, only used in schools and universities), and *Whiteboard* means a whiteboard (used regularly).

Sure, I could try out what happens if I call the whiteboard *Tafel* from now on, but I think my colleages would be confused, just because we agreed to have different words for them.

Comment: I saw it in some memory cards, and apparently they look similar, just in my childhood I saw what's a "Tafel" because now is more common to see whiteboards in any classroom, office and so on, thanks for the explanation and the example, very useful.

Comment: If a colleague would start using _Tafel_ instead of whiteboard, I'd be very confused, because I'd think he'd be talking about a grand table, as in _a table laid for ten people_.

Answer (score 11):

A *Tafel* is really any kind of panel or tablet. Usually it's something you write on (*Schreibtafel*), but not necessarily: *eine Tafel Schokolade* means "a bar of chocolate".

There are many kinds of Schreibtafel: Kreidetafel, Steintafel, Tontafel, etc. In the context of school, *Tafel* alone usually means **blackboard**, although it is a superset of all kinds of *Tafel* so it can refer to any board that you write on.

*Das Whiteboard* actually has a non-imported equivalent: **die Weißwandtafel**. This, as you can see, is also a specific kind of *Tafel*. So, to answer the question, I think it is accurate to say that *die Tafel* is a much broader word (again, it will point to a *Kreidetafel* in many contexts), while *das Whiteboard*, following its English meaning, is specifically a white *Tafel* used with colored markers.

Comment: I really like this one (+1). There is just a missing *h* in *(Schreibtafel)* in the first paragraph.

Comment: I welcome all attempts to introduce a German word for Whiteboard. But "Weißwandtafel" is unnecessarily repetitive with "Wand" and "Tafel" in one word. - For practical use, in our organisation, we just call this thing a "Tafel" as in "Schreib das mal an die Tafel" without specificially mentioning its colour. Why should we? Everybody sees that it is white.

Comment: Interesting (?) addition: in a very specific context, "Tafel" also means "Table". The context is that if the table is set, and the occasion is formal or exceptional, then you can refer to the table as "Tafel". See also: "Knights of the round table", translation: "Ritter der Tafelrunde", and "tafeln", a verb which basically means "to dine" or "to feast".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann [*Weißwandtafel*](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=Wei%C3%9Fwandtafel) is not a word I made up.

Answer (score 1):

[Whiteboards](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaktives_Whiteboard) have a different technical background. They often include some kind of camera and tracking system.

A *Tafel* in a traditional sense is a board which you wrote on with chalk.

Comment: You mean an *interactive Whiteboaard*, right? A classic [*Whiteboard*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibtafel#Whiteboard) is just a white, magnetic board writable with certain pens.

Comment: @Marzipanherz From the example sentences in the question it was pretty clear to me that the question was about interactive Whiteboards, as not classic Whiteboard would ever replace a PowerPoint presentation.

Comment: I see. I had the focus rather on the question title. It might be helpful for the OP or future readers to know that both (classical and interactive) exist.

Comment: Except for those Power Point presentations which should not have been in the first place, because a board, whatever its colour would have been the better medium.

Comment: Thorsten's remark is important. Indeed, the initial question, lower section, seems to refer to some of these clumsy (well, my opinion) things that recently appear on meeting room walls in financially better-off locations. Which, however, raises the question: how could they be called in good German, avoiding "interactive whiteboard" or "interaktive Weißwandtafel" (which is as ugly as "Lichtzeichenanlage" for "Ampel"). Is there a good German word for it already?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I know it as "interaktives Whiteboard" (also used in schools, btw),  according to Thorsten's link, it is also described that way in Wikipedia. If that isn't sufficient for you, you could ask a separate question, I guess.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: "as not classic Whiteboard would ever replace a PowerPoint presentation" - I disagree. For instance, in university settings, different lecturers prefer different media; some prefer PowerPoint (or similar) presentations, while some prefer blackboards (and whiteboads do not work that differently). Thus, obviously, a "high-tech" digital presentation and a "low-tech" vertical board for physical writing can indeed replace one another. What is more, if it *is* an interactive whiteboard, the PowerPoint presentation and the whiteboard are not mutually exclusive, so the example ...

Comment: ... sentence would not make much sense any more. (I mean: There are digital whiteboard systems that deliberately include a projector meant for digital presentations, which can be annotated on the whiteboard. While combination of digital slides and a conventional board is, of course, possible as well, I have found people to be less inclined to do so as they mostly have a strong preference for one of the options and against the other in my experience.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper What I meant (and I agree with you that the example sentence being dubious in that respect): Had I prepared a PowerPoint presentation for a potential customer, I'd not consider a classic whiteboard as a proper replacement for that. Most probably the example sentence is meant as: As the customer if you can use the interactive whiteboard for the presentation instead of a classical beamer.